# how do you create a watch that you set it from when it starts and when it ends

Tags: android, android-widget

I don't know how to do the time that you can set the time when something start to it's ends. like that you set in the calendar, which you set the time from when the start to where it ends in java. can somebody help me pleas?

Comment: For what exactly do you want this?

Comment: I want to create a program that you can enter his schedule in, I want a watch that will work between the two points that says when it starts and ends.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of Timer and TimerTask :

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
  // do stuff 
    }
};
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(task, /*when*/);
```

Refer to [schedule()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AlarmManager` in Android for performing tasks of this nature. Please remember to register the `Broadcast Receiver` in `AndroidManifest.xml` so that you can properly use the below mentioned code:

For Actual Example the Below mentioned code snippet would broadcast and intent that is specific to my application. I'll grab the intent and start the background service which performs my app specific functions. like :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ServiceStarter.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

long scheduledTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES;
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, scheduledTime,
                sender);
```

And Inside my `ServiceStarter` i'll do something like this is:

```
    public class ServiceStarter extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent serviceIntent;
        serviceIntent = new Intent(context, ActualService.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);

    }
}
```

For shutting down the task similar lines of the code for `AlarmManager` would do just in the the `ServiceStopper` we need to stop the service like:

```
public class ServiceStopper extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent serviceIntent;
        serviceIntent = new Intent(context, ActualService.class);

        context.stopService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

Please revert if you need something else too.

Comment: thank you very much, but unfortunately I did not make it work. there are errors in the "ActualService" I do not know what to do. have tried to do different java files in "src" with the "Sevice" codes.